# need help utilizing find command and xargs command

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a simple scripts that can mv every file within a folder to a folder generated from the current date.
This is my initiatives.

```
#!/bin/bash

storage_folder=`date +%F` # date is generated to name the folder 
mkdir "$storage_folder" #createing a folder to store data 

find "$PWD" | xargs -E mv "$storage_folder" # mv everyfile to the folder
```

Comment: You obviously didn't read the man page of `xargs` (and `find`)

Comment: `find | xargs` is generally speaking dangerous, unless one uses `-print0` on the `find` side and `-0` on the `xargs` side. It'll break down badly (in ways that can allow an attacker to insert filenames of their choice into your command line -- maybe someone with write access to your working directory wants to `mv /etc/passwd` into your destination, for example) with filenames with spaces, filesnames with literal quotes, filenames with newlines, filenames with backslashes... see [Using Find](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind) for a discussion of relevant best practices.

Comment: I have seen they use it with tar and mv command on youtube. but i guess it's not really practical to use it that way.

Comment: YouTube is probably not a good source for learning best practices. There are far more people who write shell scripts badly than who do it well -- and those who do it well are more likely to be curating and critiquing resources like [the Bash-Hackers' Wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/) or [the BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) and [BashFAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ) than random YouTube videos.

Comment: (To be clear -- I've seen a **lot** of security holes and other serious bugs in code written by professional sysadmins, or in developers whose focus was on C, Java, or otherwise languages other than bash; indeed, even in code shipped as part of Linux distros. And I've seen firsthand when those bugs have bitten people, to the tune of multiple TB of business-relevant data loss).

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link, its really helpfull and well writen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

xargs is not needed.  Try:

```
find . -exec mv -t "$storage_folder" {} +
```

Notes:

1. Find's `-exec` feature eliminates most needs for `xargs`.
2. Because `.` refers to the current working directoy, `find "$PWD"` is the same as the simpler `find .`.
3. The `-t target` option to `mv` tells `mv` to move all files to the `target` directory.  This is handy here because it allows us to fit the `mv` command into the natural format for a `find -exec` command.

#### POSIX

If you do not have GNU tools, then your `mv` may not have the `-t` option.  In that case:

```
find . -exec sh -c 'mv -- "$1" "$storage_folder"' Move {} \;
```

The above creates one shell process for each move.  A more efficient approach, as suggested by [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) in the comments, passes in the target directory using `$0`:

```
find . -exec sh -c 'mv -- "$@" "$0"' "$storage_folder" {} +
```

#### Safety

As [Gordon Davisson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89817/gordon-davisson) points out in the comments, for safety, you may want to use the `-i` or `-n` options to `mv` so that files at the destination are not overwritten without your explicit approval.

Comment: It's not necessary to call one `mv` per file in the POSIX case, much less one `sh` per file. Consider: `find . -exec sh -c 'mv -- "$@" "$0"' "$storage_folder" {} +`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Nice trick.  I like it.  Answer updated again with to use `$0`.

Comment: I'll add my usual exhortation to use `mv -i` or `mv -n` to avoid overwriting files if there are any duplicate names.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Good point.  I've added a section to the answer on that.